# PHP: Update a table with a different SELECT statement on a click of a button?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table on my page and the first time it is loaded is when the user enters the page. On my database table I have a BIT and on my page I have two buttons. When I click in the first button I want to show in the table the data with the bit in 0 and in the second button, the data with the bit in 1. I tried creating a function:

```
$EstadoAtivo = 0;
$EstadoEncerrado = 1;
function updateTable() {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname")

    if($showFirst){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tabela_ordens WHERE Estado = '$EstadoAtivo' ORDER BY Id desc";
    }else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tabela_ordens WHERE Estado = '$EstadoEncerrado' ORDER BY Id desc";
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}
```

And then when I click the first button I run:

```
<?php 
$showFirst = true;
updateTable();
?> 
$("#table-ordens").load('index #table-ordens');
```

and the second button is the same but `$showFirst = false;`

And inside my table I have:

```
<?php 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Cliente']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Equipamento']; ?> </td>
  <td><input type="button" name="view" value="Exibir" id="<?php echo 
  $row['ID'];?>" class="btn mostrar_info btn-block" />
  </td>                                                  
  <td><input type="button" name="view" value="Encerrar" id="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" class="btn encerrar_chamado btn-block btn-danger" /></td> </tr>
 <?php  
  }  
 ?>
```

But it doesn't work, nothing changes when I click my buttons.

Comment: How do you communicate with your DataBase? Do you do it with Ajax or do you refresh the page?

Comment: So, You want to use `AJAX` to update it without refreshing OR Don't know that you can update it using `$_SESSION`, `$_POST`, `$_GET` Request?

Comment: I know about ajax but I don't know how to do this in ajax. I'm using ajax currently to insert and update, but I couldn't find how to use it to select data and put into the table.

Comment: @Nortmar the idea is simple, `first page` query is made in the `main page`, And the other query in the `ajax page`, then you use jquery to call this `ajax page` content and put it inside the `div` that you already show the `first query` values inside of it. The concepts is same as here https://youtu.be/ejN-oAw9vC0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At First, You make your Query inside a specific `element`, And lets say a `div`

```
<div id='posts'>
  <?php 
  $query = $query = "SELECT * FROM tabela_ordens WHERE Estado = '$EstadoAtivo' ORDER BY Id desc";
  execute $query . . .
  echo values . . .  
  ?>
</div>
<button id='update'></button>
```

make your `ajax.php` page with the other query

```
<?php 
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tabela_ordens WHERE Estado = '$EstadoEncerrado' ORDER BY Id desc";
  execute $query . . .
  echo values . . .  
?>
```

Then you make your `AJAX` function and call on with `$(document).on`

```
function update() {
    $.get(. .ajax.php. . . success: $("#posts").load(data); . );
}

$(document).on('click', '#update', function(){
    update();
})
```

Keep in mind `.load()` will append the new values, If you want to remove all the previous values from the `html` and put the new ones, use `.html()`

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to your comment and the video recommended in the post comments I could make it work :) Really grateful.